# FFMPEG concat 2 files of different resolution hangs

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concat 2 videos of different size and resize it to 426x240:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0]scale=426:240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=426:240:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0];[1]scale=426:240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=426:240:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1];[v0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' concatenated_video.mp4
```

In the output I see:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1582 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1473 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 08/17/2020.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 08/17/2020.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:16.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 383 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 426x240 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 245 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
  Stream #1:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale:default
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale:default
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[vost#0:0/libx264 @ 0x7fc777006280] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or setting vsync/fps_mode to vfr
[libx264 @ 0x7fc777006580] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fc777006580] MB rate (405000000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x7fc777006580] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc777006580] profile High, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fc777006580] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'concatenated_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 426x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40], q=2-31, 1000k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 aac
[vost#0:0/libx264 @ 0x7fc777006280] More than 1000 frames duplicated  1.1kbits/s speed=4.94x
```

Process hangs and I see that ffmpeg uses 500% of the CPU. Any idea how to fix (deal with) this?

I can open both videos on my computer and play them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat of two video streams with different framerates can sometimes lead to the filter unsetting the output framerate, which basically can lead to an abnormally high framerate down the processing pipeline.

Add `-fpsmax 30` to clamp the output rate.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I will close this question as others are saying it shouldn't be posted here. I hope that this will not affect your reputation.